# How to reload Algolia cache on CRUD operations?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, algolia, instantsearch.js

Newbie here.

In Angular 5 application with instantsearch.js library, how do I reload Algolia cache from my model on CRUD operations? I am using Cloud Firestore as my database and I have a cloud function to sync the data with Algolia.

Currently, I have to refresh the browser for changes to take effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a request sent to your frontends with for example websockets, when it gets a "new data" event like that, you should call `search.refresh()`.

```
whateverListenerYouHave.on('data', () => search.refresh());
```

See also [the docs](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/v2/instantsearch.html), and some relevant issues: [instantsearch.js#2670](https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch.js/issues/2670) and [instantsearch.js#1050](https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch.js/issues/1050)

In the context of Angular InstantSearch, you'll need to make a connector to have access to the `search` (instance of InstantSearch.js)